# Mysql - Three table query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables which are used to store some user data.

`sub_domains` (experience sub domains go here. `exp_id` matches `id` in `exp` and `domain_id` matches `id` in `misc`. So the `user_id` and `exp_id` can be duplicate if a user has more than one sub domain)

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| domain_id | int(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| exp_id    | int(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`misc`

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`exp`

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| job_type   | varchar(60)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| experience | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| exp_title  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| domain     | varchar(125) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is the query I have atm that grabs data from exp:

```
$query_str = "SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.job_type, a.experience, a.exp_title, a.domain,     a.start, a.end, b.name
FROM exp a
JOIN misc b ON a.domain=b.id
WHERE a.user_id = ?";
```

I am already getting the domain name from `misc` but I also want to get the name of each sub domain from `misc` also but I don't know how to change the query.

EDIT

I worked on this a little and came up with this:

```
$query_str = "SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.job_type, a.experience, a.exp_title, a.domain, a.start, a.end, b.name,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(domain_id) FROM sub_domains sd WHERE a.id=sd.exp_id) AS subs,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM misc WHERE id IN( subs ) ) AS subcats
FROM exp a
JOIN misc b ON a.domain=b.id
WHERE a.user_id = ?";
```

It almost works, var_dump of subcats only returns the first `name` from `misc` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying your question for a while, I was able to figure out what you were after.

You can try this solution:

```
SELECT    
    a.*, 
    b.name AS domain_name,
    c.subdomain_names
FROM
    exp a
LEFT JOIN 
    misc b ON a.domain = b.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT   aa.exp_id, GROUP_CONCAT(bb.name) AS subdomain_names
    FROM     sub_domains aa
    JOIN     misc bb ON aa.domain_id = bb.id
    GROUP BY aa.exp_id
) c ON a.id = c.exp_id
WHERE 
    a.user_id = ?
```

Though I'm a bit confused as to why you have a `user_id` column in the `sub_domains` table if the `user_id` is already referenced in the `exp` table. To me, it seems like that's a duplication which could be eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.job_type, a.experience, a.exp_title, a.domain, a.start, a.end, b.name
FROM exp a
     INNER JOIN misc b 
         ON a.domain=b.id
     INNER JOIN sub_domains c
         ON a.id=c.exp_id
WHERE a.user_id = ?
```

Comment: No ... it just returns 4 or 5 of each experience.

Comment: if you want all the records from table a then try using LEFT JOIN  instead of INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you're after, but this may help.  Using LEFT JOIN since you aren't enforcing foreign keys.

```
select exp.id, exp.user_id, exp.job_type, exp.experience, exp.exp_title,
       exp.domain, exp.start, exp.end,
       GROUP_CONCAT(misc.name) as sub_domain_names
from exp
left join sub_domains
    on (exp.id = sub_domains.exp_id)
left join misc
    on (sub_domains.domain_id = misc.id)
where exp.user_id = ?
group by exp.id, exp.user_id, exp.job_type, exp.experience, exp.exp_title,
         exp.domain, exp.start, exp.end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply extend your current query :

```
SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.job_type, a.experience, 
       a.exp_title, a.domain, a.start, a.end, b.name, c.id
FROM exp a
JOIN misc b ON a.domain = b.id
JOIN sub_domains c ON c.domain_id = b.id
WHERE a.user_id = ?
```

Comment: This doesn't return anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue . As your query is fine and working well.But , you need to show all names by using `GROUP_CONCAT()` method .

Unfortunately  it shows only first name. Is it ?

Please check your `IN()` condition , if you manually put the values  inside `IN` like

`IN('1,2,3')` also, it will shows you first name.

Solutions :-

Keep your query same as well it is. But separate the below line from the query :

```
String query1= SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(domain_id) FROM sub_domains sd WHERE a.id=sd.exp_id
```

Before executing your  main query run this query first , inside DAO class ( Your DAO method).

Get the return value in a `String` then put that(query1) `String` into your main query `IN()`.

I got my expected answer from this type of DAO operation. 
Hope its help full.